# Sending google visualization chart to email

Tags: javascript, email, google-visualization

Can we send Google Visualization chart to an email client?
I tried to copy paste the javascript code while sending the email, but its been removed on the fly by gmail.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: With AlphaMail's feature _Dynamic Images_ you can copy and paste the code, take a look at this example I've written: [How to Use Google Charts in Transactional Email](http://comfirm.se/techblog/how-to-use-google-charts-in-transactional-email/).

Comment: you can easily use google image charts, works a treat, check http://datamakessense.com/kpi-emails-with-google-charts-url-parameters

Comment: you can use this to send emails with embedded images btw, if you go for downloading google image charts - the benefit of that would be that they will be displayed even when external images are disabled in the client 
http://datamakessense.com/easy-scheduled-emailing-with-python-for-typical-bi-needs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is very little JS support in email clients. so you will have to use an image chart. But you could wrap the chart in a link to the svg version.

Comment: could you provide more information on how do you mean exactly to wrap the chart in a link to the svg version? thank you :)

Comment: Inside a HTML email you can put <a href=""> </a> tags around the <img /> of the chart then the link can go to a page with the original chart on.

Answer (score 7):

*Disclaimer: I'm Image-Charts founder*.

6 years later! Google Image-Charts is deprecated since 2012, and as an indiehacker, I don't want to rewrite from scratch an image generation backend each time I started a new SaaS to just be able to send charts in email...

That's why I've built **[Image-charts](https://image-charts.com)**  and added [gif animation](https://documentation.image-charts.com/reference/animation/) on top of it (chart animations in emails are awesome!!), no more server-side chart rendering pain, no scaling issues, it's blazing fast, 1 URL = 1 image chart.

```
https://image-charts.com/chart
?cht=bvg
&chd=t:10,15,25,30,40,80
&chs=700x300
&chxt=x,y
&chxl=0:|March '18|April '18|May '18|June '18|July '18|August '18|
&chdl=Visitors (in thousands)
&chf=b0,lg,90,05B142,1,0CE858,0.2
&chxs=1N**K
&chtt=Visitors report
&chma=0,0,10,10
&chl=||||+33% !|x2 !
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this problem as well.  In order to send a chart in email, you need to render it as an image because email clients strip Javascript.

If you're using Google Charts, you'll have to run the Javascript and then export it using [getImageURI](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing).  To automate this, you need a headless renderer like [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer).

**The solution to the problem is open source**.  I wrapped chart rendering in a library and web server: https://github.com/typpo/quickchart.  This web service handles the rendering details, all you do is call the API with your data.

For example, define your chart in the query parameters:

[https://quickchart.io/chart?width=500&height=300&c={type:'bar',data:{labels:['January','February','March','April','May'],datasets:[{label:'Dogs',data:[50,60,70,180,190]},{label:'Cats',data:[100,200,300,400,500]}]}}](https://quickchart.io/chart?bkg=white&c=%7Btype%3A%27bar%27%2Cdata%3A%7Blabels%3A%5B%27January%27%2C%27February%27%2C%27March%27%2C%27April%27%2C%27May%27%5D%2Cdatasets%3A%5B%7Blabel%3A%27Dogs%27%2Cdata%3A%5B50%2C60%2C70%2C180%2C190%5D%7D%2C%7Blabel%3A%27Cats%27%2Cdata%3A%5B100%2C200%2C300%2C400%2C500%5D%7D%5D%7D%7D)

The above URL renders this image:

[image: QuickChart image render]

Hope this helps!

Comment: I can't believe you got only 2 upvotes [with me now 3]. Your wrapper is fantastic and easy to use. It covers all my needs. _Another question_: How long do you plan to run the URL https://quickchart.io/ ?

Comment: Hi Peter - paying customers allow me to host quickchart.io sustainably, and I intend to run the free version indefinitely.  I've also open-sourced the project so adopters have a form of insurance if something were to happen to QuickChart.

Answer (score 2):

Google charts could be published in 2 ways:

1. as an Image. Edit Chart-> Publish Chart-> Format : image. An image link is generated. This image link could be either used in any html page or could be embedded in any email.
2. as an Interactive Chart. Edit Chart-> Publish Chart-> Format : Interactive Chart. In this case javascript code has to be inserted. This could only be published in html pages. This could not be attached in email body as most email servers/clients do not process javascript code (AFAIK).

Answer (score 2):

3.5 years later... :)

My team at Ramen recently spun out some internal functionality into a standalone product that does just this: https://ChartURL.com

You can generate charts on the fly using an "Encrypted URL" scheme, or you can send us huge amounts of data and return a Short URL that'll resolve to an image.

It was built on top of C3js.org so there's a ton of flexibility in what you can generate.

These URLs can be used in web apps & mobile apps, but the original intent was email charts so I hope this helps!

Comment: Site has been shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't Google Charts have an API where you can just build a URL and it returns an image - no Javascript needed? It certainly used to. If you can use that, then:

a) Just put the URL in the email and let the users email client get it

b) Fetch the image with CURL and attach to the email.

Comment: you are correct, but image functionality doesn't suite my demands. I have to have svg functionality of google charts.